# unspecified minpoly in singular

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry, algebra, singular

I am learning using singular , and I run the following script in singular

> ring A1=(2^3,a),x,dp;
>   minpoly ; 
>   1*a^3+1*a^1+1*a^0

I am confused by it, 
I have not specified a monopoly for A1 rings, but the A1 have a monopoly already.

Does this means that the A1 have only 1 monopoly so we don't need to specify it?

Shengyu Shen

Comment: sorry, the script should be :

Answer (score 0):

sorry, the script should be :

ring A1=(2^3,a),x,dp;

minpoly ;

and the result of minpoly is :

1*a^3+1*a^1+1*a^0

So where does this minpoly come from?

ShengYu Shen